# Novel about Los Angeles doll museum run by feminist collective

Tags: story-identification, novel, dystopia

I read a dystopian novel set in decaying Los Angeles about a Barbie museum. But there was a collective living there building an archive about violence against women below ground. There was a horrible government that would have destroyed the archive; the Barbie museum was their cover and their recruiting ground. This was pre-1990s.

Comment: Do you know anything about how LA got so dystopian/decaying? Was this a post-apocalyptic novel, or did the author think that society was on this downward path anyway?

Comment: It's probably not the correct book, but [In the Heart of the Valley of Love](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/213998.In_the_Heart_of_the_Valley_of_Love) is set in a decaying future Los Angeles and one Goodreads reviewer does mention "a future Los Angeles - deep, underground buildings"

Comment: No, thanks, not it. The only building underground was the one where the doll museum collective lived. It was dystopian because of a catastrophic national event and totalitarianism and was probably set about now or 10 years ago.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the nature of this "catastrophic natural event"? Also, was this a full-length novel or a short-story, or something inbetween like a novella? Finally, do you remember anything about the cover art, including anything like borders or fonts that might help identify the publisher?

Comment: This might be one of Ron Goulart's "Fragmented America" books. Maybe the first one (*[After Things Fell Apart](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1866974.After_Things_Fell_Apart)*) or the second one, [*Gadget Man*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6588786-gadget-man). Must warn you, I don't think I'd want to read either!

Comment: Reviews of the first [here](https://jamesdavisnicoll.com/mists-of-time/millennial-review-xxx-after-things-fell-apart-by-ron-goulart-1970) and [here](http://www.republibot.com/content/book-review-%E2%80%9Cafter-things-fell-apart%E2%80%9D-ron-goulart-1970) and [here](https://www.blackgate.com/2022/02/26/slapdash-slapstick-ron-goulart-1933-2022/). One-line review of the second book [here](https://www.librarything.com/work/938930/reviews/155633568).

Comment: No, these are not close to the book.

Comment: It was a full-length novel, paperback.

Comment: Apologies for asking about this one again, but which country did you obtain the book in? Having an idea of whether this was a UK/US/other publisher might help narrow things down.

Comment: I got it in Berkeley California.